# Change editRecurringMode dynamically on editable template in kendo scheduler

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I want to skip the Edit Recurring dialog(which content options for "edit series" and "Edit occurrence" ) in KendoUI Scheduler while editing the past recurring events, and in other cases the Edit Recurring dialog should not be skipped.

example code:

```
editable: function(e)
{
   if(e.conditionisTrue)
   {
       editRecurringMode: "dialog"
   }
   else
   {
       editRecurringMode: "occurrence",
   },
   template: kendo.template($("#myCustomEditorTemplate").html())
}
```

Instead of:

```
editable: 
{
    editRecurringMode: "dialog",
    template: kendo.template($("#myCustomEditorTemplate").html())
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have solved this problems change by kendo.all.min.js.This is wrong or right i dont know but i have solved my problems.In new version  kedno.all.min.js to add function in editRecurringMode(e),and i have pass param by like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this problems change by kendo.all.min.js.This is wrong or right i dont know but i have solved my problems.In new version kedno.all.min.js where is

```
o.editRecurringMode:"dialog";"series"===a?n()(line no 50)
```

and i have replaced by this code"o.editRecurringMode(e):"dialog";"series"===a?n()" in kendo.all.min.js
and i have pass param

```
editable: {
        //editRecurringMode: "occurrence",
        //editRecurringMode: "series",
        editRecurringMode: function (e) {

            if (e.allowAddEdit) {

                return "dialog";

            }

            else {

                return "occurrence";
            }

        },   

        template: kendo.template($("#customEditorTemplate").html())

    },
```