# Dynamically "Delete" Icon hide show in in kendo scheduler

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile, kendo-scheduler

I have create new event in kendo scheduler.There is some problems in my scheduler.I want to show delete button only authorize person who is created this event.And I want to hide delete button who is not created this event,Only show event scheduler and hide icon.
I am so tired but not solved this problems please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to create different types of users and give them different perks. For example, the person who created that event will be an administrator. You have to create some function where the administrator will have the create and the destroy properties as true. To other users, you'll set those properties false. As for the hiding or not buttons, I suggest you to make your own custom edit form template. This was just a general idea but I hope you get the bigger picture.

updated answer:

Not only I think you should implement the CRUD operations manually but also customize the Scheduler behavior. Just like you can wire edit event and hide the save button if an user is not authorized or just like you can wire a save event and control wheather you allow or not event modifications, the same can be made with a delete event. Anyway, from what I understood, I think that using a custom editor template to control the state of any components should be enough. Basically, define a custom template and allow/disable/hide/show some widgets depending on the user that is logged in. The credentials can be loaded and used directly in the template. Check this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/eDAx), it might be useful.

Comment: Thanks you  samureira for suggestion and good idea.But here is some problems,if i have change "destroy:false" in editable template the hole icons are hide.i want to change dynamically hide delete icon  if administrator create event the admin access to delete own created event but this event show only  user and hide delete  icon.Here is my problems I have create one  controller which is use both admin and user if i have destroy is false then admin event also hide delete icon but i want to show delete icon for admin not user.I am so confused.would you min may you give me some example please..

Comment: Samureira,Like that  Exaple :                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502479/change-editrecurringmode-dynamically-on-editable-tempalte-in-kendo-scheduler/32516816#32516816